# ¿Cómo usar el setTimeOut en el ipcRenderer.on?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Cuando coloco un setTimeOut dentro de un oyente de ipcRenderer no funciona. el código se ejecuta la primera vez cada segundo pero luego ejecuta cada vez que recibe un dato.

Aquí esta el fragmento de codigo

```
window.ipcRenderer.on('data', (e, data) => {
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('datos',data)
}, 1000)
```

});

como hago para que ejecuto cada segundo?.

Comment: Con [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: Tendrías que decirnos que es exactamente lo que esperas que pase, si cambias  `setTimeout` por `setInterval` por ejemplo, lo que va a pasar es que se va a ejecutar el console cada un segundo, pero cada vez que se lance el evento, se va a crear otro timer sin reemplazar al anterior.

Comment: espero es que cada vez que se lance el evento, se demore un segundo en imprimir en consola.

Comment: Me parece que no estás calculando bien los tiempos. Resulta que cada vez que recibes un dato, no necesariamente ha pasado 1 segundo desde que recibiste el anterior, por lo tanto en consola se mostrará la primera vez luego de 1 segundo y las subsiguientes veces exactamente en el instante siguiente que se haya recibido el siguiente dato. Es decir, sólo estás demorando 1 segundo la salida por consola desde el primer dato, el resto se seguirá mostrando con el intervalo en que se recibe el evento. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Voy a mostrar una forma de hacer lo que intentas, pero la implementación de la misma sobre tu código debes hacerla tú, ya que sólo muestras parte del código de un evento y no puedo adivinar el resto.

Lo que veo que intentas hacer es claramente posible, pero tienes que tomar en cuenta ciertas limitaciones sobre el uso de la memoria física del equipo.

En primer lugar, debes entender que para lograr el objetivo debes tener una forma de ir almacenando los datos que recibes para luego mostrarlos cada 1 segundo (de acuerdo a lo que planteas en tu pregunta). Pero debes recordar que según la cantidad de datos recibidos puedes llegar a colapsar la memoria física ya que tal vez se reciban demasiados datos antes de poder ir acomodando espacio al vaciar o descartar los datos una vez mostrados.

La idea es crear una [fila o cola](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cola_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

El procedimiento es simple:

1. Se reciben datos y se ponen en la fila.
2. Pasado un tiempo establecido se muestra el primer dato de la fila y se descarta el mismo (se saca de la fila), todos los elementos de la fila avanzan un espacio (la fila se reduce en 1 elemento).
3. Mientras existan elementos en la fila repetir el paso 2.

De esta forma podremos lograr lo que necesitamos.

Para mostrarte un ejemplo, voy a escribir una clase que llamaré `enqueueClass` y en ella estableceré una propiedad llamada `list` y otra llamada `MAX`.

Recordemos que si no ponemos límite a la cantidad de elementos de nuestra fila, podríamos consumir toda la memoria física y colgar el equipo, es por ello que usaremos `MAX` como un límite máximo de elementos que puede almacenar nuestra lista.

Además implementaré la clase como un objeto que emite eventos, y para ello usaré el módulo de eventos: [`events`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/events.html#events_events). Por lo tanto nuestra clase extenderá a la clase [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

Además, crearemos 3 métodos en nuestra clase, los cuales llamaré `enqueue`, `dequeue` y `delayLog`.

El propósito de cada método es claro de acuerdo a su nombre: `enqueue => poner en cola`, `dequeue => quitar de la cola` y `delayLog => mostrar registro con retraso`.

También se emitirán 4 eventos: `start`, `enqueued`, `full`, `dequeued`. Su uso lo decides tú, yo sólo hago lo posible por mantener esto simple.

El evento `start` se emitirá cuando se ponga un elemento en la cola y este sea el primer elemento de la misma.

El evento `enqueued` se emitirá cada vez que se coloque un elemento en la cola.

El evento `full` se emitirá cuando la lista esté llena (el número de elementos de la misma sea igual a `MAX`).

El evento `dequeued` se emitirá cada vez que un elemento sea purgado de la lista.

**¿Y cómo creamos una lista (cola o fila) en JS?**

Javascript no tiene un objeto de tipo *Lista*, sólo disponemos de nuestro gran amigo `Array` y dos métodos que hacen ver a nuestro amigo como una cola. Estos métodos son [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/shift) y el muy conocido [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push).

Por último, el código:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// Clase que implementa EventEmitter
class enqueueList extends EventEmitter{
  MAX = 5;
  list = [];
  enqueue(item) {
    if(!item) return;
    if(this.list.length == this.MAX) {
      this.emit('full');
      return;
    }
    this.list.push(item);
    this.emit('Enqueued');
    if(this.list.length === 1) {
      this.emit('start');
    }
  }
  dequeue() {
    let item = this.list.shift();
    console.log(item); // <- Muestra el item por consola
    this.emit('dequeued');
  }
  delayLog(time) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dequeue();
    }, time);
  }
}

// Instanciamos la clase
let myList = new enqueueList();

// Establecemos las acciones para los eventos
myList.on('enqueued', () => {
  console.log('Element enqueued');
});
myList.on('full', () => {
  console.log('List is full')
});
myList.on('start', function() {
  console.log('Dequeue started');
  this.delayLog(1000);
});
myList.on('dequeued', function() {
  if(this.list.length > 0) {
  // si aún hay elementos en cola, se vuelve a llamar a la función
    this.delayLog(1000);
  }
});

// ejemplo de uso
let items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'];

items.forEach((item) => {
  myList.enqueue(item);
});
```

Como no puedo poner un `Snippet` con NodeJS, te dejo una imagen del proceso cuando es ejecutado en mi ordenador.

[image: Salida en consola del código actual]

Espero que con esto puedas solucionar el problema.