# ¿setTimeout, sirve para controlar el tiempo de un ciclo for?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Cuento con el siguiente problema:

Busco iterar 7 números y que cada vez que pase por cada número, crezca el conteo que se hace de los mismo e.g. (ciclo 0 r: 0, ciclo 1 r: 0 y 1, ciclo 2 r: 0, 1 y 2), ya lo he conseguido, pero me interesa sobretodo que cada vez que crezca el número se presente después del anterior es decir que se presente: (0, [después de 2 seg] 1, [después de 2 seg a partir del 1] 2) y así sucesivamente por cada crecimiento, aquí les adjunto lo que ya logré espero su *feedback*

```js
var nivel = 7;

for (let i = 0; i < nivel; i++) {
    let padTime = 2000 * i
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), padTime)
    for (let n = 0; n < (i + 1); n++){
        setTimeout(() => console.log(n), padTime);
    }    
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que uses eventos. En esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300896/c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-settimeout-en-el-ipcrenderer-on/301731#301731) doy un ejemplo del uso de eventos, podrías adaptarlo a tu necesidad. En todo caso, trataré de responder en cuanto pueda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` coloca las instrucciones en la cola de actualización del navegador; para lograr lo que deseas, seguramente deberías tenerlos anidados, pero no hay garantía de que los tiempos se respeten.

Con `setTimeout()` anidados o dentro de ciclos, todas las instrucciones se agregan a la cola de actualización:

```
console.log(0, 0) en 2000ms
console.log(0, 1) en 4000ms
tarea agregada por otro proceso y que podría retrasar las actualizaciones
console.log(1, 0) en 6000ms
console.log(1, 1) en 8000ms
// Si el proceso tardó mucho, las dos anteriores podrían ejecutarse con una diferencia mucho menor a la que estableciste
console.log(2, 0) en 10000ms
console.log(2, 1) en 12000ms
....
```

Digamos que el navegador, en cada ciclo de actualización, revisa la cola y ejecuta las instrucciones que ya cumplieron el tiempo especificado que podría ser inmediato o con algún retraso por que hubo otras tareas que se ejecutaron antes.

Con `setInterval` el funcionamiento es muy diferente: Agrega una tarea a la cola y, cuando se ejecuta, vuelve a agregarla a menos que canceles el temporizador. No hay garantía de que las instrucciones se ejecuten en el tiempo especificado, pero sí de que al menos pase ese lapso antes de la ejecución.

```js
let nivel = 7
let padTime = 2000;
let timer;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function log() {
    // Si x es igual o mayor que nivel
    if (x >= nivel) {
        // Cancelar temporizador
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        // Mostrar en consola el nivel actual (0 a 6) y respuesta (0, 1)
        console.log(x, y);
        // Actualizar número de respuesta
        y++;
        // Si pasó el límite 
        if(y > 1) {
            // Restablecer respuesta
            y = 0;
            // Avanzar nivel
            x++;
        }
    }
}
// Ejecutar una vez cada (padTime)ms
timer = setInterval(log, padTime);
```